# Inferring type parameter of method from method argument fails in Scala?: "no type parameters for method"

Tags: scala

This example is taken from an exercise of "Essential Scala" from Underscore.io.
Following is definition of algebraic sum type `Maybe[A]` which mimics some basic features of `Option[A]` and a list of `Maybe[Int]`.

```
sealed trait Maybe[A] {
  def flatMap[B](fn: A => Maybe[B]): Maybe[B] =
    this match {
      case Full(v) => fn(v)
      case Empty() => Empty[B]()
    }

  def map[B](fn: A => B): Maybe[B] =
    this match {
      case Full(v) => Full(fn(v))
      case Empty() => Empty[B]()
    }
}
final case class Full[A](value: A) extends Maybe[A]
final case class Empty[A]() extends Maybe[A]

val list = List(Full(3), Full(2), Full(1))
```

I tried to replace the elements in `list` with odd values with Empty[Int] therefore resulting `List(Empty(), Full(2), Empty())` by this statement:

```
list.map(maybe => maybe flatMap { x => if(x % 2 == 0) Full(x) else Empty() })
```

and this was the exactly same with the answer from the book.

But I got an error:

```
Error:(41, 26) no type parameters for method flatMap: (fn: Int => A$A22.this.Maybe[B])A$A22.this.Maybe[B] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Int => Product with Serializable with A$A22.this.Maybe[_ <: Int])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Int => Product with Serializable with A$A22.this.Maybe[_ <: Int]
 required: Int => A$A22.this.Maybe[?B]
list.map(maybe => maybe flatMap { x => if(x % 2 == 0) Full(x) else Empty() })
                        ^
```

So I wrote type parameter then It worked well:

```
list.map(maybe => maybe flatMap[Int] { x => if(x % 2 == 0) Full(x) else Empty() })
```

I thought it would be ok even if I don't provide the type parameter `Int` because it seems that it was possible to infer the type parameter from the type of argument for flatMap `x => if(x % 2 == 0) Full(x) else Empty()`. What is wrong? I heard that `Product` and `Serializable` automatically mix-in into case class so that the type of the function literal above is `Int => Product with Serializable with A$A22.this.Maybe[_ <: Int]` as shown in the error message. Is this related to the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Empty()`: the compiler has no reason to pick any type parameter for it other than `Nothing` (in particular, it doesn't look at `if`'s other branch). So it ends up with `Full[Int]` in one branch and `Empty[Nothing]` in another, and their common type is `Product with Serializable with Maybe[_ <: Int]`, as shown in the error message. From *this* result type, obviously the type parameter for `flatMap` can't be inferred.

When defining a trait which should only be extended by case classes, it's normal to include `trait Maybe[A] extends Product with Serializable` so they'll be subsumed in such upper bound calculation, but you'll still end up with `Maybe[_ <: Int]` (in case you are unfamiliar with this notation, it means "`Maybe` whose type parameter is some subtype of `Int`"): the compiler notices that `Full[Int]` is a subtype of `Maybe[Int]` and `Empty[Nothing]` is a subtype of `Maybe[Nothing]`, but `Maybe[Nothing]` is not a subtype of `Maybe[Int]`.

I expect you'll see the better way to fix the problem in following exercises, but for now the fix is to specify `Empty[Int]()`.